Finding mistake in a proof - irreducible variety after identification of variables
I am looking for help in identifying a mistake in the following proof:
Let $P(x,y,z)$ be a (complex) irreducible polynomial in three variables. In other words, the algebraic variety
$$Z_P:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb C^3:P(x,y,z)=0\}$$
is irreducible. Now, consider the set
$$Z_P':=\{(x,z):P(x,x,z)=0 \}\subset \mathbb C ^2.$$
This is basically the variety you get upon identifying the first two variables in $P$, projected down to $\mathbb C^2$ in the natural way. I want to say that $Z_P'$ is irreducible as well. Here is the idea why:
Consider the mapping $f:\mathbb C^3 \rightarrow \mathbb C^2$ given by:
$$f(x,y,z)=(x,z)$$
Then it is easy to see that $f(Z_P)=Z_P'$. Since $f$ is a regular mapping between algebraic varieties, it maps irreducible subvarieties into irreducible ones, meaning that $Z_P'$ is irreducible.
The thing that bothers me is the following - had I considered the set
$$Z_P'=\{x:P(x,x,x)=0\}\subset \mathbb C,$$
the same argument would show that this new $Z_P'$ is irreducible. On the other hand, $Z_P'$ is the zero set of a polynomial in one variable, and this is always reducible (assuming its degree is higher than one). But where is the issue in my original argument?
Thanks in advance.

How did you show that $f(Z_P) = Z'_P$? It seems to me that the way you defined $f$, it is just projection on $Oxz$-plane. Let $P(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$, then the map $f$ will map $(i,0,1) \in Z_P$ to $(i,1)$, but the point $(i,i,1)$ doesn't satisfy $P(x,x,z) = 2x^2+z^2=0$, so $(i,1)$ is not a point of $Z'_P$ by your definition.

@Tri thanks a lot, I now see the silly mistake. While $f(Z_P)$ contains $Z_P'$, it is not equal to it. So the conclusion about $Z_P'$ is incorrect.
Any idea on a way to proceed with proving that $Z_P'$ is irreducible under some further restrictions? (you definitely need to assume something more).

This won't work - setting $y=x$ is equivalent to intersecting with the hyperplane $V(y-x)$, and there's no reason for intersecting with a hyperplane to preserve irreducibility. For instance, if $P(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$, then $P$ is irreducible, but $P(x,x,z)=2x^2+z^2=(\sqrt{2}x+iz)(\sqrt{2}x-iz)$ is reducible.

Thanks, great answer. Do you have an idea on any "nice" conditions under which intersecting with such a hyperplane does preserve irreducibility?

The closest you can get to a good condition is any of the Bertini theorems, which only asserts that for a general hyperplane and a dimension $\geq 2$ variety the intersection is connected.

That's very interesting, I didn't know that. So if I understand correctly, you can actually proceed and say the following:
If X is an arbitrary subvariety of dimension at least n, then intersecting X with any n-1 hyperplanes will yield a connected (and hence irreducible) subvariety. Is that correct?
Is that correct? Sorry if this is quite basic, I don't touch these subjects often.

Sorry, "connected" should say irreducible in my comment above. Connected does not imply irreducible, either - consider $V(xy)$, for instance. It's not any $n-1$ hyperplanes, it's $n-1$ generic hyperplanes. (There's usually some hyperplanes where you cannot guarantee irreducibility, so we have to exclude those.)

Okay, so genericity is the key thing here that gives you the irreducibility of the intersection. Thanks a lot!

@GSofer Does not answer the question, but has relevance to it and the secondary question raised by you in the comments.
Take a Zariski-closed irreducible affine variety and a Zariski closed irreducible affine curve(even a line)  embedded in an affine space,  say $V, C\subset \mathbf{A}^n$.
The intersection being a closed subvariety of a curve has the following possibilities:
(i) empty
(ii) $S$ (i,e the case $C\subset V$)
(iii) a singleton
(iv) finite set with at least 2 points.
Constructing examples for all cases would be instructive.
Easy intuitive case over the field of real numbers which would often fail over C: A circle and a line lying in the Euclidean plane need not intersect, or could be tangent or, a secant line giving 2 intersection points making it reducible.
An interesting case over C: Take SL(2,C) regarded as an affine subvariety: $V\subset \mathbf{A}^4$ defined by the equation $xy-zw-1=0$.
Take the following infinite collection curves $L_{a,b,c}$ (actually lines)
corresponding to parametric constants $a,b,c,\in \mathbf{C}$:
$L_{a,b,c}= \{(x,ax,bx,cx)\mid x\in \mathbf{C}\}$
Now $L_{a,b,c}\cap V$ is the subset of $L_{a,b,c}$ with $x$ satisfying $(c-ab)x^2-1=0$ as easily seen by substituting in the defining equation of $V$.
So the intersection has just 2 points, namely those corresponding to the two square roots of $1/(c-ab)$ (avoid choice of constants making $c-ab=0$!).
In case $V$ were replaced by varieties defined by equations of degree $n$ (here $n=2$) we can find examples with intersections having upto $n$ points.
